# fatal error: 'openssl/evp.h' file not found cmake + make

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Operating system: macOS Catalina
I have a project that has a file called CMakeLists.txt. I ran cmake and then make, but the make command failed:

```
/Users/blablabla/Downloads/myproject/src/main.cpp:10:10: fatal error: 
'openssl/evp.h' file not found
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

I tried reinstalling OpenSSL via homebrew, linking the libraries but it still gave this error.

What am I could be doing wrong?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either openssl's dev library is not installed, or the g++ command that cmake generates probably is missing a -I.

try `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` first and if that doesn't work, make sure the openssl include dir is provided to g++.

according to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindOpenSSL.html, it creates an env var of OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR

edit: just noticed you're on OSX.  you can install the the dev libssl package with `brew install openssl`